# DSP C674X assembly how to

Tags: assembly, signal-processing

I have an assembly function X86 and same as ARM assembly that i would like to port to DSP C674x but i don't know about C674x assembly.

function: swap_stack_and_call(*stack,*func_entry,*struct_info_ret);
struct_info_ret:
entry
param
ret

x86 assembly instructions

```
    __asm {
    mov ecx, stack
    lea esp, [ecx - 4]
    and esp, -16
    mov eax, struct_info_ret
    mov [esp], eax
    call func_entry
}
```

ARM equivalent instructions

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
    "mov sp, %0\n"    
    "mov r0, %1\n"    
    "bx %2\n"          
    :
    : "r" (stack), "r" (struct_info_ret), "r" (func_entry)
    : "r0");
```

Is it possible to port / translate it to C674x DSP assembly ? How do we call assembly c674x into C function ?

Comment: The [TMS320C674x DSP CPU and Instruction Set Reference Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprufe8b/sprufe8b.pdf?ts=1602989757543) describes the assembly on the C674x. Description of the instructions starts at page 99. The syntax for writing inline assembly depends on the C compiler, so look up the compiler documentation about that.

Comment: Hi, thx for the link,

Answer (score 0):

i think it could be as hereunder:

```
LDNW    .D2     stack, *SP--
B       .S2     func
ADDKPC  .S2     info_ret, B3, 4
```

and/or as :

```
LDNW    .D2     stack, *SP--
ADDKPC  .S2 LABEL,B3, 4
CALLP   .S2 func, B3
```